# Dart Update breaking my flutter functionality for VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I start vs code, my dart extension always starts Flutter setup pub running upgrade and it doesn't stop loading. I have no logs, no errors and I cannot use anyting in VS anymore except the git plugin.
What can I do to fix this infinite loading?
Things I tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling all extensions for VS Code
- uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code

[image]

Comment: What packages have you listed in your pubspec file? Have you listed any new ones lately? Are you using strict versioning to prevent arbitrary upgrades from happening that could break your code and/or dependencies?

Comment: Can you try running `flutter packages get` in the terminal? Sometimes errors the VSCode plugin fails to display can be caught here.

Comment: It seems that my flutter SDK was the issue. I repulled it and everything is working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if Flutter fails to initialise correctly. The best way to track this down is to close VS Code entirely, and run `flutter doctor` from the terminal. If Flutter is failing to download components, it'll usually be more obvious from the terminal.

I've seen this happen where the Flutter SDK has merge conflicts in some of its internal files (possibly a result of trying to use `git` to update it/change branches). Usually this results in an error message that contains a lot of `<<<<<<<<<` characters where there should just be a version number.